# Display something in the middle of post content

Tags: matrix, content

My entry content is displayed like this:

```
{% for block in entry.postContent.all() %}
  <div class="my-4">
        {% if block.type == 'text' %}
      {{ block.text }}
    {% elseif block.type == 'image' %}
      {% for image in block.image.all() %}
        <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to display some other things in the middle of this content but have no idea how I can do it. Maybe someone have any thoughts?

Comment: You seem to only call 1 block here (`limit(1)`) so where do you need to inject content exactly?

Comment: My bad.. I tried put limit over there but it doesn't change anything. That code displays my content. Everything is one block so I was thinking maybe I can count <p> somehow and after 50% of them insert lines that I want..

Answer (score 1):

There is a `loop` variable available within your `for` loop which you might be able to use here ([docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)). This starts at 1 and increment everytime your loop *runs*.

Using `loop.index`, you could do something like this:

```
{# Fetch your blocks #}
{% set blocks = entry.postContent.all() %}

{# Counts how many blocks you have in total #}
{% set totalBlocks = blocks | length %}

{# Divide your totalBlocks by 2 and round to find the 50% mark in your content #}
{% set halfwayPoint = (totalBlocks / 2) | round %}

{% for block in blocks %}
    <div class="my-4">

        {# When you reach halfway, inject #}
        {% if loop.index == halfwayPoint %}
            the content you want to inject
        {% endif %}

        {% if block.type == 'text' %}
            {{ block.text }}
        {% elseif block.type == 'image' %}
            {% for image in block.image.all() %}
                <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It doesn't work since we put all the content in one block. My idea was to use <p> tags that seperate every paragraph. Maybe it's possible to make it work in this way?

Comment: I'm still looking for solution how to count <p> elements from matrix blocks and display in the middle. So far I went to this: `{% set blocks = entry.postContent.all() %}
{% set block = blocks[0] ?? null %}
{% set count = block.text | substringCount('<p>') %}
{% set halfwayPoint = (count / 2) | round %} ` I get half number of <p> but cannot get content displayed after that...